# Combine Pandas DataFrame based on values of Two Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, lookup

I have two DataFrames that are different sizes but contain matching values in two of the columns. I need to merge the two dataframes. The resulting data frame will have all the data from the "mini_Buyer" dataframe with the additonal column "effective" from the "mini_rank" DataFrame.

The wrinkle is that the resulting data frame should only return values in the effective column where "Division" AND "Stores" match.

```
mini_rank = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Division': ['TTH', 'LRG Animal', 'Companion', 'CG', 'TTH', 'CG', 'TTH', 'Companion'], 'Store': [100, 100, 105, 102, 102, 103, 104, 107], 'Effective':['Low','High','Low','Med','High','X-High','X-High','High']})


mini_buyer = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Division': ['TTH', 'LRG Animal', 'Companion', 'CG', 'TTH', 'CG', 'TTH', 'Companion'], 'Store': [100, 100, 105, 102, 102, 103, 104, 107], 'Other Data':['aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa'],'Effective From Rank':['?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?']})
```

My best guess just yields empty columns. I've tried a number of different "how" and 'on" arguments. All have yielded the same results.

```
merged_df = buyer_stores_event.merge(rank, how = 'left', left_on = ['Division', 'All Stores'], right_on=['Division','All Stores'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're merging on a columns `'All Stores'`, but the column is `'Stores'`. You also have different names for the dataframes you are trying to merge. So I'm not sure what your issue is since you're not sharing the actually data you are having the problem with.

But I'm assuming this is because you created a sample of the set. My best guess is that the columns you are merging on don't match (Ie. It's an `int` in one of your dataframes, while it's a `str` in the other). So check to make sure the columns `'Division'` and `'All Stores'` are the same data types in both dataframes, and that if they are strings, that there's no extra white spaces or anything like that.

```
import pandas as pd

mini_rank = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Division': ['TTH', 'LRG Animal', 'Companion', 'CG', 'TTH', 'CG', 'TTH', 'Companion'], 'Store': [100, 100, 105, 102, 102, 103, 104, 107], 'Effective':['Low','High','Low','Med','High','X-High','X-High','High']})
mini_buyer = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Division': ['TTH', 'LRG Animal', 'Companion', 'CG', 'TTH', 'CG', 'TTH', 'Companion'], 'Store': [100, 100, 105, 102, 102, 103, 104, 107], 'Other Data':['aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa'],'Effective From Rank':['?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?']})

merged_df = mini_buyer.merge(mini_rank, how = 'left', left_on = ['Division', 'Store'], right_on=['Division','Store'])
```

Comment: I will explore that! Your assessment is correct, I botched the column names when condensing to a sample df. That's what I get for trying the simple route.